# How to rename a file with square brackets using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Not trying to do anything drastic, but I'm renaming my music files from the mp3 title tags.
Came across a file this problem:-

```
$fyl = One Vision [From the Motion Picture Iron Eagle].mp3

$tmp = "tmp.mp3"

$track_title = One vision [From the motion picture Iron Eagle]

rename-item "$mp3path$fyl" -newname "$mp3path$tmp"

rename-item "$mp3path$tmp" -newname "$mp3path$track_title.mp3"
```

I get the error:-
Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'F:\Music\Queen\Live Magic\One Vision [From the Motion Picture Iron Eagle].mp3' does not exist.

The file exists!

I go through a tmp.mp3 in case the files are the same if looked at without case sensitivity.

The code works for files without square brackets, so obviously Powershell is taking them literally.

I did try replacing Rename-Item with Move-Item, but I get similar errors.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Quick suggestion to try out, have you tried escaping the square bracket characters?  
`$fyl = One Vision \[From the Motion Picture Iron Eagle\].mp3`

Comment: I am noticing no quotes on the strings, normally they should be quoted (Single quotes if you don't want to escape.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access file paths in Powershell containing special characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090312/how-to-access-file-paths-in-powershell-containing-special-characters)

Comment: $fyl is derived from Foreach ( $fyl in Get-Childitem $mp3path -filter "*.mp3" ) where $mp3path is "F:\My Music\Queen\Live Magic" and $track_title is derived from using taglib-shell.dll to get the albumartists tag from the mp3 file

Comment: your code does not show $fyl being a collection.  That would change how you need to use $fyl.

Answer (score 9):

The -LiteralPath knows how to handle special characters
try this:

```
Rename-Item -LiteralPath C:\[filename].txt -NewName filename.txt
```

Comment: Just used the -LiteralPath parameter, but it still fails to rename the file.  It produced the following:-       Rename-Item : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'LiteralPath'    Powershell is Major 2, minor 0, build -1,  revision -1

Comment: Can you install powershell v4.0? That should fix this

Answer (score 0):

I am able to new, rename, remove, and get such files.

This script should work successfully for you as well, and maybe you can use it to debug your script.

Note, that I use `Join-Path` out of habit and best practice to ensure paths are valid.

**Test Code:**

```
$mp3dir = "d:\test"
$fyl = "One Vision [From the Motion Picture Iron Eagle].mp3"
$tmp = "tmp.mp3"
$track_title = "One vision [From the motion picture Iron Eagle]"
New-Item -Path $mp3dir -Name $fyl -ItemType file -Force | Out-Null
$found = Get-ChildItem -Path $mp3dir -Filter *.mp3
"Found1:"
$found | % {$_.FullName}
Remove-Item $(Join-Path $mp3dir $tmp) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Rename-Item -LiteralPath $(Join-Path $mp3dir $fyl) -NewName $tmp -Force
$found = Get-ChildItem -Path $mp3dir -Filter *.mp3
"Found2:"
$found | % {$_.FullName}
$newName = $(Join-Path $mp3dir $($track_title + ".mp3"))
"New name:`n$newName"
Remove-Item $(Join-Path $mp3dir $newName) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Rename-Item -LiteralPath $(Join-Path $mp3dir $tmp) -NewName $newName -Force
$found = Get-ChildItem -Path $mp3dir -Filter *.mp3
"Found3:"
$found | % {$_.FullName}
```

**Test Output**

```
Found1:
D:\test\One Vision [From the motion picture Iron Eagle].mp3
Found2:
D:\test\tmp.mp3
New name:
d:\test\One vision [From the motion picture Iron Eagle].mp3
Found3:
D:\test\One vision [From the motion picture Iron Eagle].mp3
```

Comment: Tried your script, but I'm getting error similar to above where it complains about Rename-Item : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'LiteralPath'    I will keep trying to get this to work.  Perhaps I need to update my Powershell?

Comment: What is the output from `$PSVersionTable`?

Answer (score 0):

From your comments to other answers I gather, that you are using PowerShell v2.

Now, the `Rename-Item` cmdlet in PowerShell v2 does not seem to have the `-LiteralPath` parameter, which you need in order to correctly interpret a path that contains special characters such as square brackets.

An alternative cmdlet to `Rename-Item` is `Move-Item` which (curiously) *does* support the `-LiteralPath` parameter even in PowerShell v2.

Instead of:

```
rename-item "$mp3path$fyl" -newname "$mp3path$tmp"
```

try:

```
Move-Item -LiteralPath "$mp3path$fyl" -Destination "$mp3path$tmp"
```

In your question you said, that you already tried `Move-Item` instead of `Rename-Item`. But did you try `Move-Item` in combination with `-LiteralPath`?

Answer (score 0):

The `move-item -literalpath $var1 -destination $var2` method worked :-) I also found that by using `[System.IO.File]::Move( "$mp3path$fyl" , "$mp3path$track_title.mp3")`    I was able to rename the file as I wanted without having to go through a tmp file.      Later testing proved that the `move-item -literalpath` method didn't need a temporary file either.