# how to debug mixed cmd and powershell scripts to solve special character problems like ampersand &

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I am creating a dos batch script (cmd.exe) `.cmd` which through powershell elevates itself as administrator.

But if it's stored in a folder that contains both spaces and ampersand in its name, it won't work.

I am not an expert so I searched the web, but I could not find a solution or documentation to solve the problem. So I would also like to know how to debug this particular situation and the possible solutions to the problem and where to find the documentation describing the solution or the steps to get there .. (if any).

To recreate the problem: I created a folder under the desktop named "Pie & tea" without quotes. And in the folder I created a script "test.cmd" inside which I put only the essential to reproduce the problem. This is the content of the script:

```
@echo off

pause

PowerShell start "%~f0" -verb runas

pause

goto: eof
```

I run the script by double clicking on it (this is the desired mode). An error is shown with this code (I translate from italian with a translator):

```
Press any key to continue. . .
In row: 1 car: 34
+ start C:\Users\fposc\Desktop\Pie & tea\test.cmd -verb runas
+                                  ~
Ampersand (&) not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use. Use "&" to pass the ampersand as
string.
    + CategoryInfo: ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId: AmpersandNotAllowed

Press any key to continue. . .
```

And following some instructions I modified the line of code with powershell by tripling the double quotes:

```
PowerShell start """%~f0""" -verb runas
```

But the cmd window opens and after pressing the space the UAC starts and after giving the consent **another window appears for a moment but it closes immediately and I could not see any errors**.

I have seen on the web any solutions using single quotes `'` or the powershell escape character `` ` `` or the caret `^` of the dos batch or the `--%` parameter of the powershell etc.
But i was unable to resolve.
I do not put the attempts made here because I copied in a stupid way (since I am not familiar with the mixed cmd / powershell operation) and I made numerous random attempts combining the various solutions. Without any positive outcome.

I have also seen solutions that I would like to evaluate, such as:

1. change directories and use relative paths.
2. prepare string variables and replace characters.
3. Use powershell -encodedcommand to pass parameters.

> > > But the preferred solution is the one that explains how to escape characters on the single line of code `PowerShell start "%~f0" -verb runas` and how to get there and the reference documentation.

Some links visited:

[VBS Shell.Application and PowerShell Start-Process do not escape ampersands internally](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/2419)

[Quoting issues with PowerShell](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/blob/dev/doc/quoting-issues-with-powershell.md)

[Issues on windows when the username contains &](https://github.com/jorangreef/sudo-prompt/issues/97)

[Executing PowerShell script via explorer context menu on items containing ampersands in their names](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/1304527)

[Stackoverflow: batch file deal with Ampersand (&) in folder name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33351455/batch-file-deal-with-ampersand-in-folder-name)

[Stackoverflow: How to access file paths in PowerShell containing special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12090312/how-to-access-file-paths-in-powershell-containing-special-characters)

[Stackoverflow: How to pass strings to powershell from cmd with ampersands in values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57699262/how-to-pass-strings-to-powershell-from-cmd-with-ampersands-in-values)

---

Comment: Does it still have the same effect after using the `-File` parameter? `PowerShell -File "%~f0"`

Comment: @Abraham Zinala. I tried but the `-File` parameter says it only accepts powershell .ps1 scripts. The script instead is a .cmd, and gives an error: `Unable to process -File 'C:\Users\fposc\Desktop\Pie & tea\test.cmd'. The file has no 'ps1' extension. Please provide a valid Windows PowerShell script file name and try again. ` I don't know ho do elevated with `-File`

Comment: Why use cmd to start powershell to start a .bat file ?

Comment: @Theo, Because the script is written in dos batch as I wrote above.

Comment: The .cmd script check if is elevated. If not elevated , it auto-elevate through powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Debugging tips:**

- If something goes wrong on the *PowerShell* side, you'll see the error message in the calling `cmd.exe` session; to print the command line that PowerShell itself sees, prepend `[Environment]::CommandLine;`  to the command(s) being passed.<sup>[1]</sup>
- To make PowerShell's [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) cmdlet (whose built-in alias is `start`) launch the batch file in a `cmd.exe` process that *keeps the session open*, invoke `cmd.exe` explicitly, with `cmd /k`, and pass it the batch-file path. Once you're sure everything works as expected, replace `/k` with `/c` (to create a session that terminates when the batch file terminates).

The **primary problem** in your case:

- Regrettably, **if a batch-file path contains `&` characters, a bug in `cmd.exe` requires *manual `^`-escaping* of the `&` *as well as spaces***, and possibly other `cmd.exe` metacharacters, even if the path is enclosed in `"..."` as a whole; **additionally, it seems that the *full* batch-file path must be used on invocation** (which `%~f0` ensures):

  - For instance, to invoke `C:\foo\a & b.cmd`, `cmd /k "C:\foo\a & b.cmd"` is *not* enough - you must use `cmd /k "C:\foo\a^ ^&^ b.cmd"`
  - The command below uses a [`-replace` operation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) to perform this `^`-escaping in PowerShell code, on the value of `%~f0`, which `cmd.exe` expands to the batch file's full path.

The following solution:

- uses aux. environment variables to make it work in most situations, even with paths containing other exotic characters, such as `$`, `%` and `'`.
- also includes support for passing arguments through on invocation.

See the bottom section for the evolution of the solution, which includes detailed explanations.

```
@echo off

:: Save the full path of this batch file in an aux. environment variable.
set "__THISFILE=%~f0"
:: Save the arguments received in an aux. environment variable.
:: Note: The space after "=" is required for the PowerShell command 
::       to also work if *no* arguments were passed.
set __ARGS= %*

:: Unless already elevated, relaunch this batch file,
:: with arguments passed through.
:: Note: Replace `exit /b` with just `exit` to 
::       close the current console window after relaunching.
net session >NUL 2>NUL || (powershell.exe -noprofile -c "Start-Process -Verb RunAs cmd /k, ($env:__THISFILE -replace '[ &%%^]', '^$&'), $env:__ARGS" & exit /b)

:: Reset the aux. variables.
set __ARGS=
set __THISFILE=

echo Now running with elevation. Arguments received:
echo.  %*
```

---

**Evolution of the solution above**:

**If your batch-file paths do not contain `'` characters:**

Embedded `'...'` quoting is used in the PowerShell command below, so as to avoid having to *escape* embedded `"` quotes, which can get tricky; this assumes that the batch-file path itself contains no `'` chars (see below if your paths *do* contain `'` chars.)

```
@echo off

:: Unless already elevated, relaunch this batch file with elevation.
net session >NUL 2>NUL || (powershell.exe -c "Start-Process -Verb RunAs cmd /k, ('%~f0' -replace '[ &]', '^$&')" & goto :eof)

echo Now running with elevation.
```

Note:

- `net session >NUL 2>NUL` is a simple trick to test if the current process is elevated (being run as admin) or not: it only succeeds in elevated sessions (reflected in exit code `0`, which the `||` and `&&` operators implicitly act on).
- `-c` (`-Command`) makes it explicit that command(s) are being passed to `powershell.exe`; while not strictly necessary, it is a good habit to form, given that `pwsh.exe`, the *PowerShell (Core) 7+* CLI, now *requires* it (see the linked CLI documentation below).
- `/k, ...` creates an *array* of arguments, which are positionally passed to the `-ArgumentList` parameter of `Start-Process` - in essence, `Start-Process` builds a command line from the executable name, `cmd`, and all arguments by string concatenation with spaces behind the scenes - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69427699/45375) to your follow-up question for details.

---

**If your batch-file paths contain `'` chars., embedded `"..."` quoting must be used**:

- With [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the *Windows PowerShell* CLI, the most robust approach - which is indeed required here - is to **use `"^""`** (sic) to escape each embedded `"`, as shown below.
- (By contrast, [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the *PowerShell (Core) 7+* CLI now fortunately accepts **`""`**.)

```
net session >NUL 2>NUL || (powershell.exe -nop -c "Start-Process -Verb RunAs cmd /k, ("^""%~f0"^"" -replace '[ &]', '^$&')" & goto :eof)
```

---

**If your batch-file paths contain `$` chars. *and* `'` chars., an *aux. environment variable* must be used**:

`$` chars. alone wouldn't be a problem if you used embedded `'...'` quoting, but if `'` are also present, embedded `"..."` quoting isn't an option, because PowerShell would treat the `$` chars. as the start of a *variable* reference.

See the solution at the top.

---

**If you additionally want to support passing *arguments* to the batch file**:

Note: The solution at the top now incorporates this approach, while also handling a wider array of exotic batch-file paths.

To prevent further quoting headaches, an *aux. environment variable*, `__ARGS` is used in the code below to store all arguments that the batch file received (`%*`), which the PowerShell code can then access via `$env:__ARGS` on re-invocation.

```
@echo off

:: Save the arguments received in an aux. environment variable.
:: Note: The space after "=" is required for the PowerShell command 
::       to also work if *no* arguments were passed.
set __ARGS= %*

:: Unless already elevated, relaunch this batch file,
:: with arguments passed through.
net session >NUL 2>NUL || (powershell.exe -nop -c "Start-Process -Verb RunAs cmd /k, ("^""%~f0"^"" -replace '[ &]', '^$&'), $env:__ARGS" & goto :eof)

:: Reset the aux. variable.
set __ARGS=

echo Now running with elevation. Arguments received:
echo.  %*
```

---

<sup>[1] A simple example (call from `cmd.exe`): `powershell -c "[Environment]::CommandLine; '%OS%'"`</sup>