# In Powershell what is the comma for, how does it work in this code example?

Tags: powershell

I just [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69424941/how-to-debug-mixed-cmd-and-powershell-scripts-to-solve-special-character-problem) about a problem and the suggested code has some obscure points for me.

Specifically on this line of code

```
powershell.exe -c "Start-Process -Verb RunAs cmd /k, ('%~f0' -replace '[ &]', '^$0')"
```

1. I would like to know what the comma after the `cmd /k` represents.
   What's this? How does it work? **Is there a link to the documentation explaining this ?**
2. What's is the `$0` in the last part. `'^$0')"`

---

Comment: I realize I forgot to answer your second question: `-replace '[ &]', '^$0'` is an application of the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375), and `$0` (`$&` would work too) is a placeholder for what the regex `[ &]` matches, i.e. either a space char. or `&`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) call embedded in your Windows PowerShell CLI (`powershell.exe`) call uses *positional* parameter binding, for brevity:

- `cmd`, as the first positional argument, binds to the `-FilePath` parameter, i.e. the name or path of the executable to launch.
- `/k, (...)`, as the second positional argument, binds to the `-ArgumentList` parameter, which accepts an *array* of arguments to pass the target executable, whose elements are separated with `,`

`Start-Process` then builds a *command line* behind the scenes, by joining the `-FilePath` argument and the `-ArgumentList` array elements with spaces, and launches it.

As an aside:

- The way `Start-Process` builds the command line is actually broken, because no on-demand quoting and escaping is performed - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62784608/45375) for background information; in your specific case, however, the problem doesn't surface.
- To work around the bug it is actually preferable in general to pass a *single* string to `-ArgumentList` that contains *all* arguments to pass; however, in this case that would have complicated quoting (you'd need an embedded `"..."` string or an explicit string-concatenation expression), so the simpler solution of enumerating the arguments with `,` was chosen.
- See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65617895/45375) for  how to discover a given cmdlet's *positional* parameters; in short: invoke it with `-?` (`Start-Process -?`) and, in the relevant parameter set, look for the parameters whose *names* are enclosed in `[...]`; e.g.
  `Start-Process [-FilePath] <System.String> [[-ArgumentList] <System.String[]>] ...`