# How to escape poison character in this mixed cmd / powershell code?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I asked for a first explanation "[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69424941/how-to-debug-mixed-cmd-and-powershell-scripts-to-solve-special-character-problem)" and "[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69426889/in-powershell-what-is-the-comma-for-how-does-it-work-in-this-code-example/69427699#69427699)" but going to try a more complex situation I was unable (after two hours of trying) to understand how to solve. I read how the regular expression works but nothing, I went into the ball.

The modified code is this:

```
(Fsutil Dirty Query %SystemDrive%>Nul)||(powershell.exe -c "[Environment]::CommandLine; Start -Verb RunAs cmd /k, ("^""%~f0"^"" -replace '[;,()= &^]', '^$&')" & echo exit)
```

and the folder with the poison characters is this:

```
C:\Users\fposc\Desktop\Pie & tea % @ ' $^
```

I have tried to escape the ^ in the regular expression with \^ but don't work. I have escaped also ( and ) with \( and \). But nothing work:

```
(Fsutil Dirty Query %SystemDrive%>Nul)||(powershell.exe -c "[Environment]::CommandLine; Start -Verb RunAs cmd /c, ("^""%~f0"^"" -replace '[;,\(\)= &\^]', '^$&')" & exit)
```

I added the round brackets because I wanted to put all possible characters to make the code as generic as possible.

I don't know if I was right to open another question. Maybe I should change the original question? Since other combinations are possible and not having understood the mechanism I could open many other similar questions. What do you advise me to do?

Comment: My recommendation is to dispense with cmd.exe and just write the entire script in PowerShell. (IMO things will be more consistent, easier to understand, and less frustrating.)

Comment: Asuming that your match is a group, and not a literal string, there are several reserved characters which should be escaped. I'd have to assume similarly with your replace string too. This seems to me to be clearly a case that you have not researched the `-replace` operator or RegEx. In my opinion you should do that and make a resonable attempt at both ensuring that your replace command is correct, before attempting to correctly escape it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **problem is the presence of `$` in your folder name**, which causes the PowerShell command to interpret it as the start of a variable reference.

The workaround is to use an aux. environment variable to store the batch file's full path and let PowerShell perform its escaping based on this variable's value:

```
:: Unless already elevated, re-invoke this batch file with elevation,
:: via PowerShell.
set "__THISFILE=%~f0"
Fsutil Dirty Query %SystemDrive% >Nul || (powershell.exe -c "Start-Process -Verb RunAs cmd /k, ($env:__THISFILE -replace '[ &%%^]', '^$&')" & exit)
```

I have updated [the answer to your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69425727/45375) to incorporate this approach, which now shows a - hopefully - robust approach to on-demand re-invocation of a batch file *with elevation*, including support for arguments.